# get middle value from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching

let say i've got a list of values, with such a format:

> BookIndex - value what i need - random stuff

```
BookIndex - B 12x - AXD39
BookIndex - A 99a - PZT00
```

...

Question: how to get value what i need with as little functions as possible?

Output

```
B 12x
A 99a
```

Comment: Answer: start by telling us what you want.

Comment: B 12x, A99a and so on, middle value

Comment: select SUBSTRING(FieldName, 12, 6) from Table1

Comment: If you have any control over the design you should consider splitting this into 3 columns. What you have here violates 1NF and as you have discovered is a real pain to work with.

Answer (score 0):

answer based on subject of your question: SUBSTRING(FieldName, StartIndex, Length)

> any general answer? because there are no static length of value that i want.

Find StartIndex and End index. In your samples you need text between char '-'

```
select SUBSTRING(TextData, CHARINDEX('-', TextData), CHARINDEX('-', TextData, CHARINDEX('-', TextData) + 1)) as E1 from [Untitled - 1]
```

Comment: any general answer? because there are no static length of value that i want.

Comment: select CHARINDEX('-', TextData) as E1 ..... will help you to find StartIndex for char '-'

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(T.stringbehinddash
                 ,0,charindex('-',T.stringbehinddash) - 1)
from
(select substring(test,charindex('-',test) + 1 ,len(test))
 as stringbehinddash
 from mytable) T
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2937/9)